# Upload image to Google Storage?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage

I need to send a file to a servlet which will then upload the file to google cloud storage.

I cannot upload the file directly from the JSP page, I need this action will be from the servlet.

I have tried so many things that I don't know what to paste here.

I have uploaded a file to google cloud storage(GCS), but GCS doesn't know what the file is and cannot open it.

Comment: You really should make an effort to list the things you've tried. This will help people answer your question.

Comment: Is your file shows in google cloud?

Comment: As @taylorthurlow said, could you list the things you have tried and also how did you upload the file? We don't have enough information to help you.